# Enlaces blade y cada enlace con un parámetros para futura consulta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, blade

Al colocar los siguientes enlaces Blade con parámetro "bebida", etc. no llega el parámetro al controlador si hago un dd($categoria). ¿Está mal puesto el parámetro?

Una web tiene 4 enlaces y cada uno lleva un parámetro ("bebidas", o "legumbres", etc.) que se utilizará para hacer una consulta en el controlador "productoController:

VISTA:

```
<a href="{{ url('/productos',categoria='bebidas') }}">Bebidas</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos',categoria='legumbres') }}">Legumbres</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos',categoria='frutas') }}">Frutas</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos',categoria='bolleria') }}">Bolleria</a>
```

CONTROLADOR (web.php):

```
Route::any('/productos/{categoria}','ProductoController@show');
```

MODELO (ProductoController.php):

```
public function show($categoria)
    {
        dd($categoria);
}
```

¿Por qué los parámetros puestos así no llegan y devuelve página en blanco?

Answer (score 0):

Para generar  url's en blade puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="{{ url('/productos/bebidas') }}">Bebidas</a>
//En caso de usar objetos
<a href="{{ url('/productos/'.$categoria->nombre) }}">$categoria->nombre</a>
<a href="{{ url("/productos/{{$categoria->nombre}}") }}">$categoria->nombre</a>
```

Si tienes alguna duda puedes revisar la documentación sobre generación de url's de laravel [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls)

Comment: Entonces lo que en html hacemos para pasar parámetro así: www.web.com?categoria=animales ¿Cómo sería con Blade?

Comment: En blade es {{ url('/productos/bebidas') }}, esto en el html se vería www.web.com/productos/bebidas, sin url amigable se vería www.web.com/productos?categoria=bebidas

Answer (score 0):

en tu vista deberías usar:

```
<a href="{{ url('/productos/bebidas') }}">Bebidas</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos/legumbres') }}">Legumbres</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos/frutas') }}">Frutas</a>
<a href="{{ url('/productos/bolleria') }}">Bollería</a>
```

La ruta la tienes definida como `/productos/{categoria}`, lo que pongas luego del segundo slash será tomado como el parámetro "categoria".